Two identical SQLiteExceprion in one line
I have two identical errors in one line using SQLCipher.
I am checking the password for correctness. If the parameter is entered incorrectly, two exceptions occur.
I looked at this page to see if the password I entered was correct. When I repeated the code, I still got two exactly the same exceptions on the same line of code. One exception I can catch, the other is logged.
TaskOpenActivity:
        binding.openDatabaseFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @OptIn(markerClass = ExperimentalBadgeUtils.class)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("TaskCalendarPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("PassphraseMD5", TaskApplication.getInstance().md5(binding.passphrase.getText().toString())).commit();

                SharedPreferences preferences = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TaskCalendarPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String passphrase = preferences.getString("PassphraseMD5", "");
                Log.d("TaskCalendarLog", passphrase);
                try {
                    TaskApplication.getInstance().loadAllData();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                    Log.d("TaskCalendarLog", "Incorrect password");
                }
            }
        });

TaskApplication:
    public void loadAllData() {
        taskCalendarDBHelper = new TaskCalendarDBHelper(this);
        try {
            taskCalendarDBHelper.loadAllTasks();
            taskCalendarDBHelper.loadAllNotes();
            taskCalendarDBHelper.loadAllDayAlarms();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

TaskBDOpenHelper:
    public void loadAllTasks() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TaskCalendarPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        passphrase = preferences.getString("PassphraseMD5", "");
        Log.d("TaskCalendarLog", passphrase);

        TaskManager taskManager = TaskManager.getInstance();
        //SQLiteDatabase actionsDatabase;
        //actionsDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, passphrase, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, hook);
        try {
            taskCalendarDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, passphrase, null, null, hook); // <--- Exception here
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        //actionsDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = taskCalendarDatabase.query(TaskCalendarDBHelper.TASK_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int taskInt = cursor.getColumnIndex(TASK);
            int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(DATE);
            int time = cursor.getColumnIndex(TIME);
            int hasAlarm = cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_ALARM);
            int hasNotification = cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_NOTIFICATION);
            int isDone = cursor.getColumnIndex(IS_DONE);
            int wasNotifiedIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(WAS_NOTIFIED);
            int wasAlarmedIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(WAS_ALARMED);

            boolean wasNotified;
            boolean wasAlarmed;

            int id = taskManager.getMaxId();

            do {
                if (cursor.getInt(wasNotifiedIndex) == 1) {
                    wasNotified = true;
                } else {
                    wasNotified = false;
                }
                if (cursor.getInt(wasAlarmedIndex) == 1) {
                    wasAlarmed = true;
                } else {
                    wasAlarmed = false;
                }

                Task task = new Task(cursor.getString(taskInt), cursor.getString(date), cursor.getString(time), cursor.getString(hasAlarm), cursor.getString(hasNotification), cursor.getString(isDone));
                task.setId(id);
                task.setWasNotified(wasNotified);
                task.setWasAlarmed(wasAlarmed);
                taskManager.getTaskList().add(task);
                //Log.d("TaskCalendarLog", taskManager.getTaskList() + "");
                id++;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            taskManager.setMaxId(id);
        }
        cursor.close();
        taskCalendarDatabase.close();
    }

If you remove the try-catch block, you will get two absolutely identical errors.
2024-09-30 20:11:57.458 18829-18829 SQLiteDatabase          com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      E  Failed to open database '/data/data/com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar/databases/TaskCalendarDatabase.db'.
                                                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: file is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_schema;
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:973)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:628)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:240)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:202)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:475)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:189)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:181)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1028)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:840)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:812)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:929)
                                                                                                        at com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar.DataBase.TaskCalendarDBHelper.loadAllTasks(TaskCalendarDBHelper.java:194)
                                                                                                        at com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar.Application.TaskApplication.loadAllData(TaskApplication.java:98)
                                                                                                        at com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar.Activities.OpenDatabaseActivity$1.onClick(OpenDatabaseActivity.java:61)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7184)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7157)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:821)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27660)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
2024-09-30 20:11:57.458 18829-18829 TaskCalendarLog         com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      D  Incorrect password

UPD:
This exceptions show in log after removing all try-catch blocks and trying to open db with incorrect password.
    2024-10-01 10:27:12.848 23502-23502 SQLiteConnection        com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      I  Database keying operation returned:0
2024-10-01 10:27:13.421 23502-23502 sqlcipher               com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      D  ERROR CORE sqlcipher_page_cipher: hmac check failed for pgno=1
2024-10-01 10:27:13.421 23502-23502 sqlcipher               com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      D  ERROR CORE sqlite3Codec: error decrypting page 1 data: 1
2024-10-01 10:27:13.421 23502-23502 sqlcipher               com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      D  ERROR CORE sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_error 1
2024-10-01 10:27:13.421 23502-23502 SQLiteLog               com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      E  (26) file is not a database in "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_schema;"
2024-10-01 10:27:13.427 23502-23502 SQLiteDatabase          com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      E  Failed to open database '/data/data/com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar/databases/TaskCalendarDatabase.db'.
                                                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: file is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_schema;
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:973)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:628)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:240)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:202)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:475)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:189)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:181)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1028)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:840)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:812)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:929)
                                                                                                        at com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar.DataBase.TaskCalendarDBHelper.loadAllTasks(TaskCalendarDBHelper.java:193)
                                                                                                        at com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar.Application.TaskApplication.loadAllData(TaskApplication.java:98)
                                                                                                        at com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar.Activities.OpenDatabaseActivity$1.onClick(OpenDatabaseActivity.java:60)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7317)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7291)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:838)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28247)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8676)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
2024-10-01 10:27:13.427 23502-23502 AndroidRuntime          com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      D  Shutting down VM
2024-10-01 10:27:13.431 23502-23502 QarthLog                com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      I  [PatchStore] createDisableExceptionQarthFile
--------- beginning of crash
2024-10-01 10:27:13.431 23502-23502 QarthLog                com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      I  [PatchStore] create disable file for com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar uid is 10246
2024-10-01 10:27:13.432 23502-23502 AndroidRuntime          com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar, PID: 23502
                                                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: file is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_schema;
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:973)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:628)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:240)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:202)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:475)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:189)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:181)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1028)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:840)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:812)
                                                                                                        at net.zetetic.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:929)
                                                                                                        at com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar.DataBase.TaskCalendarDBHelper.loadAllTasks(TaskCalendarDBHelper.java:193)
                                                                                                        at com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar.Application.TaskApplication.loadAllData(TaskApplication.java:98)
                                                                                                        at com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar.Activities.OpenDatabaseActivity$1.onClick(OpenDatabaseActivity.java:60)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7317)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7291)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:838)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28247)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8676)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
2024-10-01 10:27:13.456 23502-23502 Process                 com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar      I  Sending signal. PID: 23502 SIG: 9
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (23502) for package com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar ----------------------------

Sorry for my bad English. It's Google Translate.

Are you sure the path '/data/data/com.andrewpeterson.todocalendar/databases/TaskCalendarDatabase.db' is correct?

Yes, it's correct.

The exception message is "file is not a database". Could be possible that the file is broken / corrupted?

@GonzaloOdiard It's ok to get exception, because I try open db with wrong password, but why I get two exceptions instead of one.

@GonzaloOdiard BD is encrypted with SQLCipher.

why catch (SQLiteException e) { throw e; } ? (multiple times)

@user85421 To throw an exception above. Or is this incorrect?

just not needed - if you don't catch it, it will just continue to the caller (like with throw)

@user85421 I catch it in caller (TaskOpenActivity) and it will Log.d(bla-bla-bla incorrect password) and it's push it in log.


what I have commented above is: you do not need to write catch (SQLiteException e) { throw e; } - it does the same as without it; 2) what is your real problem: having a second Exception THROWN; or having the Exception logged ? Maybe openOrCreateDatabase is also logging the Exception before throwing it (maybe you can/must change log settings)


@user85421 My real problen is a second exception. Shouldn't the exception from the openOrCreateDatabase be caught by my try-catch block?

what exactly do you mean by "is a second exception" -- again, is the called method throwing second exception; or is the first exception also being logged? I suspect it is being logged since the log contains the message Failed to open database ..., and after logging, the method is throwing the same exception which you can catch

If you are invoking the OpenDatabaseActivity from MainActivity then you should not then start the MainActivity, rather you should just finish the OpenDatabaseActivity and it will return to it's parent/invoking activity (MainActivity). i.e. remove the line startActivity(intent); (obviously setting the Intent would then not be required).

@MikeT MainActivity is not first activity. TaskOpenActivity is the first activity,

@user85421 UPD for you.

Thankyou. Now it is clear that your problem is having two Log entries for the same Exception, and not having two identical exceptions on the same line! As I already wrote, the driver is doing the first log entry ("Failed to open database '/data/...") before forwarding (re-throwing) he exception. The second log entry ("FATAL EXCEPTION: main ...") is done since the (forwarded) exception is not being handled. Maybe you must change the log-settings for the driver, if you want it not doing the logging itself (I do not use SQLite neither Android)

@user85421 Thanx! Can you write an answer and write, how can I change log settings?

sorry, I can't, quoting myself: > I do not use SQLite neither Android

@user85421 Sorry but nothing helps.

I got it! It's OK, because Android core SQLiteDatabase.java output exception to log before throw it to me (I don't know why):

    private void open() {
        try {
            try {
                openInner();
            } catch (SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException ex) {
                onCorruption();
                openInner();
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open database '" + getLabel() + "'.", ex); //<-- Put to the log before catch in my code.
            close();
            throw ex;
        }
    }


Please post code as text and not as an image.

@Abra Can I put image and code?
